# Set/Get element custom element properties

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm trying to add a custom property to an existing element by I find it impossible.

There's a Map of attributes to my element but there's not properties Map.

I tried doing something like this:

```
el.someProperty = 'Some value';
```

but this line produced an error that el does not have get$someProperty.

I would like to do something similar to jQuery that you can just use

```
el.prop('propName', 'value');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```dart
el.attributes['someProperty'] = 'Some value';
```

if that doesn't work use

```dart
el.dataset['someProperty'] = 'Some value';
```

this way the added attribute will get a `data` prefix and probably named `data-some-property` (haven't tested)

Comment: Then I guess you have to use `dataset` instead of `attributes`. If you want to assign to a Polymer element you can `el.someProperty = 'value'` or `(el as MyElement).someProperty = 'value'`

Comment: Setting ``el.dataset['someProperty'] = 'Some value'`` creates an *attribute* named ``data-someProperty``. Doing ``$(el).prop('someProperty', 'Some value')`` does not create an attribute but adds a field to the ``el`` object, which is what the asker said they were trying to do but got an error.

Comment: @Louis thanks for clarification. Dynamically adding fields is not supported in Dart. Adding an attribute is the closest one could do.

Comment: My bad. Dart hides the DOM so thoroughly that `el.attributes["foo"] = "blah"` works.